# How to use Vue computed, data,.. properties in an electron app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

Im using https://github.com/oliverfindl/electron-vue-boilerplate which uses "vue": "^3.0.11" and try to use the data() and computed below:

```js
<template>
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <button role="button" @click.prevent="count+=2">count is: {{ count }}</button>
    <p>Edit <code>components/HelloWorld.vue</code> to test hot module replacement.</p>
    <div id="example">
        <p>Original message: {{ message2 }}</p>
        <p>Computed reversed message: "{{ reversedMessage }}"</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
/* eslint-disable indent */

    "use strict";

    import { ref } from "vue";

    export default {
        props: {
            message: String
        },
        setup() {
            const count = ref(0);
            return { 
                count,
            };
        },
        data() {
            return {
                message2: "Hello"
            };
        },
        computed: {
            // a computed getter
            reversedMessage: function () {
            // `this` points to the vm instance
                return this.message2.split("").reverse().join("");
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

The result is not expected, message2 is not displaying, and with computed property reversedMessage it is not returning even if I return a hard coded string:

[image]

Comment: In a fresh project your code shows expected result. If `count` returned from your `setup()` function works properly, you could also declare the `message2` ref inside it. You can also move your computed value there. Example with computed value inside setup in [Vue docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#computed-values)